# Run Turbo C++ in Freedos

Tags: c++, ide, dos, turbo-c++

I want to **run Turbo C++ in FreeDos**. I used to run it in DosBox but now I decided to test the FreeDos in my desktop PC.

But every time I try run it the cursor blinks and nothing happens (after I enter the command and press enter) , the prompt does not return( C:> ) and I have to restart my system by pressing the power button. My question is:

1. How can I actually run it? Does it require extra drivers or files?
2. If it cannot be run, Do you any other C++ IDE? Maybe your own IDE?

*P.S. I have installed FreeDos using the freedos option of Rufus.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-should-i-not-use-turbo-c

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this? Believe me, you don't.

Comment: "I want to run Turbo C++ in FreeDos" - no you don't. You want to get a modern compiler where you can use modern C++ and you want to run it on a modern OS. Forget about Turbo C++, it is ancient, pre standard and not worth your time (if it teaches you *anything* it will be *bad* habits and *bad* C++ - don't use it).

Comment: My school uses Turbo C++ in Dosbox (I'm a student). So I use it. We are taught to use and code in that. But I want to test it in FreeDos.

Comment: Also I noticed Dos Navigator 2 is not running, it also hangs the computer as mentioned above. Maybe I thing the configuration is not properly set, I had to create config.sys but I don't know what to put in. I also doubt whether it is due to absence of HIMEM.sys and other files?

Comment: @ARAVIND I M: consider however learning C++11 (since TurboC++ teaches you an *obsolete* programming language) at least and using a good free software C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and/or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)..). BTW Linux distributions are nice environments to learn C++ and programming (they have `g++`), so you could consider installing one on your PC

Comment: do internal and external commands work? What happens if you type `dir` or `mem`. If `dir` works and `mem` don't than you got wrong paths or are missing OS files ... I added answer with some hints what might be wrong

Comment: @ARAVINDIM added bullet **#6**

Answer (score 3):

**FreeDOS** is not **MS-DOS** so incompatibilities are to be expected. However I did not come into contact with **FreeDOS** but here are some hints (from **MS-DOS** so they should more or less apply to **FreeDOS** as well).

1. **Without `himem.sys` you have no high memory**

   so you got just 640 KByte instead of 1 MByte for everything. That is not much as some programs requires even 540 KByte...
2. **without `Emm386.exe` or `QEMM386` you got no XMS memory**

   If my memory serves well than also the **DPMI** drivers will not work which turbo needs.
3. **without proper `autoexec.bat` and `config sys` nothing works**

   you do not have paths, device drivers (mouse,**CDROM**,etc.), and sets (like sound card). If you do not know what to put in them copy them from **DOSBOX** (minus the **DOSBOX** mount lines). No paths usually also means no `command.com` so you got no shell so no commands would work
4. **what file system you use?**

   I would not go beond **FAT16** for older DOS. Use **FAT32** only for newer **MS-DOS** versions (from win98). Do not use **NTFS** or **EXT** even if you got drivers those caused problems all the time...
5. **Computer speed**

   many **DOS** programs where based on Borlands **CRT** library. That caused a lot of problems later on as computers speed-up. If I remember correctly there was this `runtime error 200` caused by it. To remedy such programs you can do 2 things. Patch or recompile the CRT lib in them (there are some fixes out there) or go to BIOS and turn off **CPU CACHEs** (L1,L2..). That will turn your modern computer into really fast 386 That should still pass the CRT init. Otherwise the timing is off and programs crash/hangs etc ... The **DOSBOX** emulator is designed to run programs at the original speeds instead of as fast as possible speed, so no further adjustment should be necessary if using that.
6. **Memory**

   The old **DOS** can not handle more than 64 MByte and some programs have problems even with that. The safest way is to limit the available memory to 32 MByte. I usually did it using **RAMDISC** and or **SMARTDRIVE** buffers so only 32 MByte of memory is left for the **DOS** programs. (You can use the `mem` command to see what is your status if you see negative numbers you are crossing barriers and need to increase usage of **SMARTDRIVE** or **RAMDISK**).

   Do not forget to save the **SMARTDRIVE** buffers time to time and before exit to avoid loss of data if reset or crash/hang/freeze occur... It is a good idea to use **Volcov commander** (or Norton commander) with predefined menu for such operations. You can even associate file extentions with viewers editors and **IDE**s with it. So if you execute `asm` or `cpp` it got compiled or opened in your prefered **IDE** end so on...

Here example of `autoexec.bat` and `config.sys` (taken from my ancient **MS-DOS** rescue disc):

**Autoexec.bat**

```
@echo off
PROMPT $P$G
PATH e:\rescue;e:\rescue\dos98;e:\rescue\vcnew;e:\rescue\pack;e:\rescue\views
e:
cd rescue
SET TEMP=e:\rescue\temp
SET BLASTER=A220 I5 D1 H5 P330 E620 T6
SET SOUND=e:\rescue\SB16
SET MIDI=SYNTH:1 MAP:E MODE:0
e:\rescue\SB16\DIAGNOSE /S
e:\rescue\SB16\AWEUTIL /S
e:\rescue\SB16\MIXERSET /P /Q

goto %config%
:a
:b
:c
:d
:e

lh gmouse
LH vc
```

**Config.sys**

```
;devicehigh=e:\rescue\dos98\interlnk.exe
shell e:\rescue\dos98\command.com e:\rescue\dos98 /P
lastdrive=M
files=50
buffers=8
stacks=0,0
DOS=HIGH,UMB

[menu]
menuitem=a,QEMM
menuitem=b,EMM EMS
menuitem=c,EMM NOEMS
menuitem=d,STANDART
menuitem=e,RAMDISK 32MB
menudefault=d,1

[a]
device=e:\rescue\dos98\qemm386.sys RAM BE:N
[b]
device=e:\rescue\dos98\himem.sys 
devicehigh=e:\rescue\dos98\emm386.exe rammax
[c]
device=e:\rescue\dos98\himem.sys
devicehigh=e:\rescue\dos98\emm386.exe noems
[d]
device=e:\rescue\dos98\himem.sys
[e]
device=e:\rescue\dos98\himem.sys
devicehigh=e:\rescue\dos98\ramdrive.sys 32767 /e
```

It has boot menu where you can select what configuration you want. Just change the drive letters and paths. Beware `:a,:b,...` and `[a],[b],...` are not drive letters those are menu entries.

`shell` is the command.com location. the `gmouse`  is mouse driver (not part of **DOS** you need to download it), `vc` is Volcov commander filemanager (you do not really need it and also it is not part of **DOS** but having it really is a good idea.) You can ignore the SB16 and sound blaster settings as it is high unlikely you got the same sound card or even fully SB compatible without any emulation/driver present.

`e:\rescue\dos98\` is location of my **MS-DOS** commands so replace it with your location.

The `cd` command changes directory, and `lh` loads into high memory instead of base memory to preserve Base memory.

How ever if I where you to avoid compatibility problems I would try to obtain **MS-DOS 6.22**.

So my bet is you got any combination of all the issues mentioned rendering your OS inoperable.

Comment: DOSBOX emulation is deliberately slow so timing is right.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know and stated it in bullet **#5** already: `DOSBOX emulation is so slow so it passes easily without any adjustments.`

Comment: That is ambiguous.  I read it as the emulation being so badly written that it were slow all by itself.  It is different if the authors deliberately did an effort to calibrate to a certain speed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen hmm got your point if you have better formulation please edit it in ...